# Erro ao executar teste em Python 3.6.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert

Esta dando erro ao executar a def teste() para testar a def questao().
Porque estaria dando erro no retorno da função teste?

```
def questao():
    lista_nomes = []
    nome = ''       
    x = 0    
    reader = csv.DictReader(arquivo)

    for linha in reader:
        nome = linha['full_name']        
        lista_nomes.append(nome)
        x += 1

        if  x == 20:
            break

    return lista_nomes
```

**Teste**

```
def teste():
    r = questao()
    assert (
        isinstance(r, list) and
        all(isinstance(y, str) for y in r)
    )
```

**Erro abaixo:**

```
C:\Users\perei\devpy\python-1\teste.py:25: AssertionError: assert [] == ['C. Ronaldo'..., 'Robert Pererira', ...]
```

Comment: Pelo que parece você tem dois tipos de teste, o primeiro para saber se `r` é uma lista e outra para saber se cada elemento da lista tem _strings_. Eu separaria estes testes, algo como `assert isinstance(r, list) == True` e `assert all(isinstance(y, str) for y in r) == True` pois são validações distintas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem certeza que essa falha do teste é dessa função de teste mesmo?
Por que ela não compara isso - e a mensagem de erro do assert mostra de fato uma lista populada com os nomes lidos - que deve ser o retorno correto da função `questao`.

Voce está usando pytest, certo? (O pytest modifica o `assert` do Python para dar mensagens de erro com os valores comparados - o `assert` sozinho não mostraria os dois valores que estão sendo comparados).

Na saida completa que você tem no terminal deve ter o nome e o ponto certinho da função de teste que está falhando - possivelmente é uma outra.

Se não for, por favor, atualize a sua pergunta com o código do modulo da sua função de teste -inclusive com as importações. E confirme se está usando o  pytest ou outra biblioteca terceira para rodar os testes.

Comment: Desculpe, mas não tenho acesso ao arquivo de teste.
Tem alguma diferença utilizar ou não o virtualenv para fazer os testes?

Comment: Não há diferença alguma em usar ou não o virtualenv para os testes.